# Creating two layer of geom_points with custom palette and only one legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot with a data set similar to:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 1:4, col_1 = rainbow(4), group = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b'))
```

I would like to plot the points and then have a border around the point depending on which group they are in (a or b). It is only of interest to show the legend for the group.

Below is my trial, but I cant get everything to work together:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = group), shape = 21, size = 3) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = x, col = col_1)) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the final plot should look like.  Does replacing the two `geom_point()` layers with one like this one help? `geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group, fill = col_1), shape = 21, size = 3) `

Comment: That code produces an error

Comment: Whoops, note you also need `scale_fill_identity()`.

Comment: Your code works fine. You just need to remove the stroke from the first points and adjust the shape of the second points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To formalise my comment to an answer:

Your code works fine. You just need to remove the stroke from the first points and adjust the shape of the second points

I am enlarging the dots in order to make this clearer, and have exaggerated the size of the second points.

Note that your intended effect is not very well visible because this type of color contrast is very difficult to perceive. There are also things happening in your retina which make it difficult to see the colors of the points in the middle.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 1:4, col_1 = rainbow(4), group = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b'))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = group), shape = 21, size = 4, stroke = NA) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = x, col = col_1), shape = 1, size = 10, stroke = 3) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Another way is to do everything in one call as suggested by [user aosmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2461552/aosmith), but then you need to remove the stroke in the legend keys -

```r
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = group, col = col_1), shape = 21, size = 4, stroke = 3) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(stroke = c(NA, NA))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>